# Place a point upon coordinates on a 3D object model in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, 3d-model

I am building a Three.js App (React Template, if it's important). I have this 3D object model that should act like the Planet Earth in app. And I've got this space station model. I wanna rotate the station around the world by giving some specific coordinates every other second. My question is: 
How can I place the space station above London, for example, if I have this coordinates:
`long: 45.926013877299` and `lat: 46.524648101056` (random)

This is the way I load the object:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load("path/to/model", function (gltf) {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vector3 has a method called [`Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords(radius, phi, theta)`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords). You can use this to convert your distance, lat, & long into an X, Y, Z point in space:

```js
const radius = 100; // Distance from center of Earth

const polar = 180 - (lat + 90);
const phi = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(polar);
const theta = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(long);

mesh.position.setFromSphericalCoords(radius, phi, theta);

// Final result
console.log(mesh.position.toArray());
```

Notice `phi` and `theta` have to be in radians, not degrees, so I had to convert them. I also had to change the value of latitude. This is because `phi` is measured as 0° at the North Pole, and 180° at the South Pole.

Comment: I suppose that `mesh` is the space station, but when I give it `mesh.position.setFromSphericalCoords()` will it be positioned related to my Earth? Or all the objects are positioned in the center when they are added to the `scene`, so it won't matter?

Comment: Try it, and see what you get.

Comment: Is the `mesh` my space station, right?